# Why does my javascript mouse event not fire?

Tags: events, mouse, javascript

Here's what I thought was simple code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            function Foobar(id) {

                self = this;

                self.id = id;
                self.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                self.canvas.style.border = '1px solid black';
                document.body.appendChild(self.canvas);
                self.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', self.onMouseDown, true);

                self.onMouseDown = function(e) {
                    console.log(self.id);
                }

            }            

            var s1, s2;

            function onLoad() {
                s1 = new Foobar(1);
                s2 = new Foobar(2);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='onLoad()'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does the console not pop up with the id number?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRn7v/

Comment: Attack of the global, `var` is not optional with self. Also self has meaning in JavaScript, pick a different variable name.

Comment: Ah, what a great example of an implicit global variable `self` colliding with the existing global variable `self`. Remember kids, declare your variables.

Comment: @epascarello It has meaning in the browser environment (as it it is a reference to the global object), but it doesn't have a meaning in JavaScript *per se*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', self.onMouseDown, true);
```

In this line, `self.onMouseDown` is `undefined`, because you assign it only afterwards. Possible quickfixes to get it work:

- move the function creation / assignment above the usage
- move the `onMouseDown` function to the prototype (bad, no local `self` in the scope)
- don't use `self.onMouseDown`, but `self.canvas.onmousedown` (cross-browser-safe with traditional event registration)

Also, your `self` variable is global. With a working handler attachment, both clicks will log `"2"`. And, the `self` variable is not needed in the most places you use it - the only need for it is in the event handler.

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRn7v/2/

Answer (score 3):

You must assign the method on `self` before binding the event listner

**FIXED**

http://jsfiddle.net/landau/VRn7v/3/

Answer (score 2):

`self` is a property of the `window` object and is generally a bad variable name. Also, your `self` variable is an implicit global because you are missing the `var` keyword. Finally, you are binding the event handler before it is declared.

```
function Foobar(id) {
    var that = this; // pick a better name, and use "var"
    that.id = id;
    that.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    that.canvas.style.border = '1px solid black';
    document.body.appendChild(that.canvas);

    that.onMouseDown = function(e) {
        console.log(self.id);
    }; // missing semicolon

    // bind the handler after declaring it
    that.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', that.onMouseDown, true);
}
```

Comment: I never knew `self` was the `window` object. I've never seen anyone use `self` to ref the window object.  Frankly, I don't believe it's a bad choice for a var name. T

Comment: @jbabey: It is a property of `window`, yes, but why should it be a bad variable name (for a local variable)?

Comment: @Bergi http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing "This can lead to confusion, as it may be unclear which variable subsequent uses of the shadowed variable name refer to."

Comment: I don't think anyone would suspect it to be `window.self` when there is a explicit (and common) declaration `... = this;` at the top of the function. But thanks for the ammo if I'd came into a discussion on the `this` pointer's name, I personally prefer `that`, too :-)